# Convert an existing SVG image map to responsive

Tags: svg, responsive-design

I have an SVG map of India downloaded from Wikipedia. I Want to use it in my website, the problem is the map is not responsive. I want to make it work as responsive keeping all the coordinates/ path intact as in the original image.

With this i want to call a click event on any state in any screen size of the map.

Please check the link for the map http://jkcomdelhi.com/INDIA.svg

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `width` and `height` values.  At the moment they are hard-wired to specific values.  Change them to `"100%"`, which will make the SVG image expands to fill its container.

Edit the SVG file and change:

```
<svg ... width="210mm" height="297mm"
```

to:

```
<svg ... width="100%" height="100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle on click event on each path element or on all svg element [example js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anton_S_Pilipenko/phdascwn/3/)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].onclick = consoleLogOnClick;
function consoleLogOnClick(e) {
    console.log('click', e.target);
}
```

You can specify [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on each path to show specific value such as name of the state.